# How to select the entire set of images to put into the video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, selection-tools, file-browser

I've seen videos on how all one has to do is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select an entire bunch of images to create/edit a movie in the *VSE* from images. However, that was in an older version then 2.77.

There has to be a better way to grab all of the images when adding strips/images in the video editing. I rendered 30 secs of video, taking 5 hours, and ending up with 900 images. When I went to add them all to the *Add Image Strip* section in the *File Browser*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> did not work. Selecting the first image then holding the shift button and clicking on the last image did not work, either.

Keying <kbd>B</kbd> for *Box Select* did not work properly because it does not drag through all of the images (it only selects the ones that you can see within the defined box).

**Basically, what is the proper way to import all of the images at once into the video editor?**

I can provide screenshots if you guys need them.

Comment: Did you try just plain 'A'?

Comment: Just **A**, not Ctrl A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>A</kbd>, not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

If you key <kbd>A</kbd>, it will select all the images in the folder that you have navigated to. If you key <kbd>A</kbd> again, it will deselect all of the images.

[image]

Comment: what has come to be the natrual way of selecting all no longer applies in Blender, it has strayed .... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the [file browser](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/file_browser/introduction.html) press <kbd>A</kbd> to select/deselect all files.

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> can be used to select/deselect multiple files, *one at a time*.

Dragging the <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> can be used to select a range of files.

Some other shortcuts available are <kbd>I</kbd> to create a new directory. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to rename a file. <kbd>X</kbd> to delete a file.